# Can you invoke nonstatic method within a static method?

Tags: java, eclipse

Book answer:  you cannot invoke a nonstatic method within a static method(unless you create an object to serve as the calling object of the non static method). I don't get the part in bracket, I tried creating object in static method and eclipse said "unreachable code". Can someone explain why and give an example too. Thanks
(language is java)

```
public class RoundStuff {
    public static final double PI = 3.141459;
    public static double area(double radius){//Area of circle
        return(PI*radius*radius);
    }
    public static double volume(double radius){//Volume of sphere
        return((4.0/3.0)*PI*radius*radius*radius);
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.print("I am not parasyte");
    }

}

import java.util.Scanner;


public class RoundStuffDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter radius");
        double radius = keyboard.nextDouble();
        RoundStuff round = new RoundStuff();
        System.out.println("A circle of radius " + radius + " inches");
        System.out.println("has an area of " + round.area(5.5) + " square inches.");
        System.out.println("A sphere of radius " + radius + " inches");
        System.out.println("has a volume of " + RoundStuff.volume(radius) + " cubic inches.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the code that is giving the problem and someone can try to explain

Comment: `round.area(5.5)` is a static call on an instance. What is the exact message eclipse gives you, and what part do you not understand?

Answer (score 2):

Java lets non-static methods call other non-static methods without specifying an object reference explicitly. It is understood that the invocation is performed on the same instance on which the current non-static method has been invoked, i.e. the instance that you can access by referencing `this`.

Static methods, on the other hand, must provide the object. Here is an example:

```
class Example {
    public void one() {
        System.out.println("one");
    }
    public void two() {
        one();   // <<== #1
        System.out.println("two");
    }
    public static void three() {
        Example e = new Example();
        e.one(); // <<== #2
    }
}
```

On the line marked `#1` above you call `one()` without specifying on what object you are calling it. Line marked `#2`, however, must specify the object on which the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of creating an object to serve as the calling object of the non static method.

```
public static void call() {
    new Object().doSomething();
}

public class Object {
     public void doSomething() {
          // Your code to do something
     }

}
```

Comment: I would normally do what the other answers are showing if I needed to use the object for other things in the method but this is what the book answer is implying and what I would use if all I needed from the object was calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

Say you've got a class with two methods, one static and one non-static, like this:

```
class Simple {
    public static void doStuff () {
        doMoreStuff();
    }

    public void doMoreStuff() {
        System.out.println("doing more stuff");
    }
}
```

This won't compile since `doStuff` can't call the non-static method. However, the documentation you are referring to indicates that you can call a non-static method by creating an object to serve as the calling object. This means creating an instance of Simple, and then calling `doMoreStuff` on that instance:

```
class Simple {
    public static void doStuff () {
        Simple simple = new Simple();
        simple.doMoreStuff();
    }

    public void doMoreStuff() {
        System.out.println("doing more stuff");
    }
}
```

This is a rather contrived example, but I often find it handy when working with the `main` method (which must be declared static) so that you aren't then declaring the rest of your methods static.